# What is the meaning of a NULL catalog?

Tags: jdbc

[DatabaseMetaData.getSchemas()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSchemas--) states that `TABLE_CATALOG` may be `NULL`. What is the meaning of a `NULL` catalog in this context?

Answer (score 0):

[Catalogs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_catalog) are the SQL-92 name for a thing which you can think of as the database itself. Each catalog contains schema(s); each schema contains table(s). It's possible for one JDBC connection to see multiple databases or catalogs, that's up to the driver and RDBMS itself.

Some RDBMS will implement explicit catalog name(s), others will not. The SQL-92 standard allows them to leave catalog_name and/or schema_name as `null`, should they not support that level of distriction.

In this context, the Javadoc is simply reminding you that a schema might not have a catalog name at all. It also tells you this about schema name. Only table names and column names *have* to exist.

Comment: I have a specific case where this answer doesn't seem to hold. Using SQL Server (jtds driver), I am seeing other JDBC methods returning the database name as the catalog, but `getSchemas()` is returning a `NULL` instead. Is it possible that a `NULL` catalog maps to the "default" database (the database that unqualified schemas/tables are resolved relative to)?

Comment: That seems very likely. The SQL-92 specification says you can refer to a table as `table_name`, `schema_name.table_name` or `catalog_name.schema_name.table_name`. If either schema or catalog name are left out, the appropriate context will apply.